# Esper epl case statement - can you say if X is in (A, B or C) then Y

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

```
create expression getID {
  X =>
    case
        when X in (A, B, C) then Y
    end
};
```

This is what I want but I don't know if it is possible or what the syntax is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already got it.

```
create schema Event(location string, sensor string);

create expression getID {
  X =>
    case
        when X in ('A', 'B', 'C') then 'Y'
    end
};

select getID(location) from Event;
```